# Copy data between online and offline servers via Sql command

Tags: sql-server, insert, server, connection

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Offline Server_name].[demo].[dbo].[Company] ON
INSERT INTO [demo].[dbo].[Company](Id, Name)
SELECT Id, Name
FROM [Online server_name].[SmartDistributorToy].[dbo].[Company]
SET identity_insert [demo].[dbo].[Company] OFF
```

The error that I get is:

> Cannot find the object "Offline Server_name.demo.dbo.Company", because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Answer (score 3):

The Offline_Server_Name and Online_Server_name named SQL Server instances should be defined to the current SQL Server instance

You can link an other SQL Server instance by [creating as Linked Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx)
Please refer to SQL tutorial. After SQL Server linked server definition is created you can then use the alias in SQL codes

You can alter IDENTITY_INSERT on a local server database table

When I tried following it works without a problem

```
set identity_insert [db_currentserver].[dbo].[Company] on

    insert into [db_currentserver].[dbo].[Company]
        (
            Id,
            Name
        ) 
    select 
        Id,
        Name 
    from 
        [LinkedServer].[db_remoteserver].[dbo].[Company] 

set identity_insert [db_currentserver].[dbo].[Company] off
```

db_currentserver is a database created on current instance
db_remoteserver is database on the remote SQL Server instance which is defined to current SQL Server instance as a linked server

Comment: but this query is working in to the  offline server to offline

Comment: Hi Arvind.  @Eralper is correct.  When you query a database this is done using a connection.  Each connection is limited to one instance of SQL Server.  Unless the SQL Server you are connected to is [linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to another.  Are you running this query against the online or offline server?

Comment: The object name 'Server_name.Passwor.database_name.dbo.Company' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.           this error are again

Comment: Problem probably is IDENTITY_INSERT for a database table on a Linked Server. You can change identity_insert parameter on a database table located on the current instance but it seems not possible for a remote server

Comment: Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  This error are generated